# JS Drag and Drop Upload Photo

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Как реализовать данную дропзону?

Как я понимаю нужно отвести отдельные div для вкидываемой картинки?

И вопрос в плане описания картинки или файла, а именно его размер, JS описывает в байтах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
(function(window) {
  function triggerCallback(e, callback) {
    //  if(!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') {
    //   return;
    // }
    var files;
    if (e.dataTransfer) {
      files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    } else if (e.target) {
      files = e.target.files;
    }
    callback.call(null, files);
  }

  function makeDroppable(ele, callback) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('multiple', true);
    input.style.display = 'none';
    input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      triggerCallback(e, callback);
    });
    ele.appendChild(input);

    ele.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      ele.classList.add('dragover');
    });

    ele.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      ele.classList.remove('dragover');
    });

    ele.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      ele.classList.remove('dragover');
      triggerCallback(e, callback);
    });

    ele.addEventListener('click', function() {
      input.value = null;
      input.click();
    });
  }
  window.makeDroppable = makeDroppable;
})(this);
(function(window) {
  makeDroppable(window.document.querySelector('.demo-droppable'), function(files) {
    console.log(files);
    var output = document.querySelector('.output');
    output.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

      if (files[i].type.indexOf('image/') === 0) {
        output.innerHTML += '<img class= "imgSize" src="' + URL.createObjectURL(files[i]) + '" />';
      }
      output.innerHTML += '<p>' + files[i].name + '</p>';
      output.innerHTML += '<p>' + files[i].size + 'byte</p>';
    }
  });
})(this);
```

```css
/* form action */

.title-section {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #686867;
  margin:20px 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
 .title-section {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 428px) {
 .title-section {
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 339px) {
 .title-section {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
 }
}

.section {
  background: #edece7;
}

.demo-droppable {
    background: #fff;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-top: 12px;
  }
  .demo-droppable.dragover {
    background: #748190;
  }

  .myBtn {
   background: #f0ede6;
   color: #c8b4a0;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 18px;
   border-radius: 0px;
  }

  .fc {
   color: #999;
   background: none; 
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
   border-radius: 0;
   margin-top: 10px;
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 14px;
  }

    .form-control:focus {
   color: #666;
   background: none; 
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
   border-radius: 0;
  }

  .form-image {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .submitBtn {
   font-family: Roboto;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 16px;
   width: 160px;
   height: 40px;
   background: #baa187;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 0px;
   margin: 20px 0;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 430px) {
   .submitBtn {

   }
  }

  .containerSize {
   width: 60%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding-top: 5px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 936px) {
   .containerSize {
    width: 75%;
   }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .containerSize {
    width: 100%;
   }
  }

  .imgSize {
   width: 100px;
   float: left;
  }

.output {
 display: inline-block;
}

/* end form action */
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- form action -->
<div class="section">
  <div class="container containerSize">
    <h1 class="title-section">Please fill in the form</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="name" class="form-control fc" id="name" placeholder="Name*">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="phone" class="form-control fc" id="phone" placeholder="Phone number*">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control fc" id="email" placeholder="Email*">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="model" class="form-control fc" id="model" placeholder="Watch brand/model*">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="year" class="form-control fc" id="year" placeholder="Year">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="serial" class="form-control fc" id="serial" placeholder="Serial if knowns">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control fc" name="material" id="matrial">
        <option>Box</option>
        <option>Papers</option>
       </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="price" class="form-control fc" id="price" placeholder="Desired amount in BYN" style="margin-top: 14px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="other" class="form-control fc" id="other" placeholder="Additional information">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="demo-droppable">
            <img class="form-image" src="img/clock.png" alt="">
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn myBtn" onclick="file_explorer();">Add files</button>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">or drag and drop files here</p>
            <div class="output"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn submitBtn" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#call">Submit →</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end form action -->
```